# Ms Azure cognitive quick start Speech to Text (adding phrases for accuracy)

Tags: python-3.x, azure-active-directory, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I want some added accuracy in the text File converted from audio (.wav) as mentioned above,
I wrote the following code.

```
phrase_list_grammar = speechsdk.PhraseListGrammar.from_recognizer(reco)
PhraseListGrammar(impl_phraseListGrammar)
phrase_list_grammar.addPhrase("PHRASE1")
phrase_list_grammar.addPhrase("PHRASE2")
#from_recognizer(recognizer: azure.cognitiveservices.speech.Recognizer)
```

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d3d53bae877d> in <module>
----> 1 phrase_list_grammar = speechsdk.PhraseListGrammar.from_recognizer(reco)
      2 PhraseListGrammar(impl_phraseListGrammar)
      3 phrase_list_grammar.addPhrase("PHRASE1")
      4 phrase_list_grammar.addPhrase("PHRASE2")
      5 #from_recognizer(recognizer: azure.cognitiveservices.speech.Recognizer)

NameError: name 'reco' is not defined
```

The codes are taken from the Ms Azure Add phrase documentations. However it is resulting into an error as can be seen above.

Can someone suggest how I can overcome this error?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because the recognizer is not initialized. Try initializing the recognizer and passing it to the PhraseListGrammar.

import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

reco = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)
phrase_list_grammar = speechsdk.PhraseListGrammar.from_recognizer(reco)
PhraseListGrammar(impl_phraseListGrammar)
phrase_list_grammar.addPhrase("PHRASE1")
phrase_list_grammar.addPhrase("PHRASE2")

Answer (score 0):

The Speech Services with a Phrase List, you can improve the accuracy of speech recognition. Currently, Phrase Lists supports only English for speech-to-text. Please follow the below document how to use pharse lists.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-phrase-lists#how-to-use-phrase-lists.

Comment: I saw your suggestions. The 1st link you have provided has already been tried by me. In fact the codes I have posted here above are taken from the link you have provided. I am not sure why the python codes provided by Ms Azure documentation for adding Phrase List to increase accuracy are even giving error. Might I need to define "reco" as the error suggests.  I exactly need a help on that part of the code where I got the error. Moreover the 2nd link provided by you is based on Java not in python. I was looking for the relevant python codes.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Please share link to the code that you are trying to check. Please check @user1180781 answer for the error that you are facing.